# Change quick edit terms list to radio buttons

Tags: quick-edit

is it possible to remove the current tax term checklist from the quick edit screen?  i have switched the metabox for the "subject" taxonomy, to radio buttons, and would like to do the same in the quick edit box.

i don't see any filters/hooks for changing the existing method, only an action for adding new items to the quick edit screen.  is my only solution, therefore with javascript?  quick edit only works w/ javascript enabled anyway.

[image: screenshot of quick edit]

Comment: How would you handle the child terms/cats?

Comment: welllll... i haven't gotten that far yet.  at the moment, i am assuming that if you are limiting to a single term then that term is the parent level (no parent/child relationships). shaky assumption, i know, but it is where i am right now.

Comment: AFAIK, jQuery. I've got some answers about [Quick Edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12615+%22quick+edit%22), and one about [Radio Buttons](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/58527/12615), that may be of use.

Comment: @helgatheviking So maybe it's too early for a question? ;)

Comment: @kaiser - maybe, but at the same time, turning the checkboxes into radios will still be a problem later. also, not everybody needs hierarchical taxonomies.

Comment: Then how about limiting this to "non hierarchical taxonomies"?

Comment: that's fine. in theory i think i'll be able to expand the solution to cover hierarchical taxonomies at a later time.

Comment: @kaiser i have definitely figured out how to use this w/ hierarchical taxonomies, using a custom Walker and some jquery to set check the correct radio on the opening of the quick edit link.  well, atleast it works for Categories just now, but i will expand to other taxonomies. but there doesn't seem to be a way to REMOVE the post tags from the quick edit screen, short of switching a taxonomy's show_ui to false in the global $wp_taxonomies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve this by setting the show_ui to false for specific taxonomies... but only on the edit.php screen.  Then I added custom columns with my own custom quick edit to mimic the regular quick edit but using a custom Walker.  If you add columns with a taxonomy name, WordPress automatically generates the quick edit, so you have to alter the taxonomy name somehow: I chose to prepend the taxonomy name with "radio-".  The end result can be seen in my [Radio Buttons for Taxonomies](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/radio-buttons-for-taxonomies) plugin.