# Use radio buttons & checkboxes for post categories

Tags: posts, categories, buttons, radio

For my users, I need them to be able to have both radio buttons and checkboxes in the categories when posting.

I have [seen a solution](http://www.livefreedietravelling.com/tech-web/radio-button-categories-in-wordpress) to make the checkboxes when selecting a category radio buttons, so that a user can only ever choose 1 category. However, I have a scenario where two categories are mutually exclusive and the rest are a free for all.

So, the user MUST choose between category A/B. But can then have free choice of categories C/D/E/F/G/H, ETC

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,

Ian

Comment: If you make category A/B in select box and other category in checkbox then it will be done.

Comment: Thanks @KuljeetSingh - but do you need to edit core WP files to do this or can you do this elsewhere?

Comment: Take a look here for more information: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58524/how-to-select-one-major-category-or-custom-taxonomy-for-a-custom-post-type