# Make parent category not selectable when it has child categories

Tags: categories, jquery, filters

I'm trying to find a way of disabling the selection of the parent category within Wordpress 3.5.1 (post editor screen) **only** when that parent category contains child categories.

My structure:

- Category 1 (no children, allow users to post, keep selection option)
- Galleries (parent category WITH children, remove selection option to stop users posting)

  - User 1 (child category, allow user to post, keep selection option)

A jQuery solution to disabling the section of **all** parent categories (regardless of having child categories or not) can be found here:

[Make parent categories not selectable](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22836/make-parent-categories-not-selectable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I disabled the parent boxes to avoid shifting parents to the left.

```
add_action( 'admin_footer-post.php',     'wpse_98274_disable_top_categories_checkboxes' );
add_action( 'admin_footer-post-new.php', 'wpse_98274_disable_top_categories_checkboxes' );

/**
 * Disable parent checkboxes in Post Editor.
 */
function wpse_98274_disable_top_categories_checkboxes() {
    global $post_type;

    if ( 'post' != $post_type )
        return;
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery( "#category-all ul.children" ).each( function() {
                jQuery(this).closest( "ul" ).parent().children().children( "input" ).attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' )
            });
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

However, once the categories are pulled out of order for that horrid "feature" that moves them to the top of the box, the jQuery fails. I borrowed this code from [a plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-checklist-tree/).

```
add_filter( 'wp_terms_checklist_args', 'wpse_98274_checklist_args' );

/**
 * Remove horrid feature that places checked categories on top.
 */
function wpse_98274_checklist_args( $args ) {

    $args['checked_ontop'] = false;
    return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin, it will solve your issue

https://wordpress.org/plugins/adjust-admin-categories/

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to use this with Custom Posts, replace where it says `post` in the if statement with the `slug` of your post type.

With Custom Taxonomies, replace where it says `#category-all` with the name of your taxonomy (e.g., `#taxonomyname-all`).

Your situation will most likely be both if you are looking at this.

For multiple taxonomies/post types at the same time: One simple option is to duplicate the entire code, and in addition to the changes above, make any new name where it says `wpse_98274_disable_top_categories_checkboxes` - the `98274` is just referencing this page (look at this pages URL) and not calling anything special in WordPress. Or more elegant is to make multiple if statements.