# Customize a WP_Posts_List_Table class

Tags: wp-admin

How can I customize output of tables of records in wp-admin/edit.php? What options are available for editing  `display_tablenav('top')` and `display_tablenav('bottom')` before outputting in class `WP_Posts_List_Table`?

I would like to insert my block between the table where records are displayed and the filters, for example: `<h3>Titlle</h3>`. No matter what. The Codex is written:

> This class's access is marked as private. That means it is not intended for use by plugin and theme developers, but only by other core functions and classes.

Maybe there is some way that does not change the kernel.

Comment: Could you be more specific on what exactly do you wish to achieve?

Comment: I would like to insert my block between the table where records are displayed and the filters

Comment: And what kind of a block?

Comment: Any block. For example: <h3>Titlle</h3>. No matter what. The codex is written: "This class's access is marked as private. That means it is not intended for use by plugin and theme developers, but only by other core functions and classes." Maybe there is some way that does not change the kernel

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you find [`apply_filters()` or `do_action`](http://ottopress.com/2011/actions-and-filters-are-not-the-same-thing/) in the core files, you'll have an entry point.

If not, [jQuery is never enough](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/58525/12615). And case it's not enough, some [heavy trickery](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A73+%2Bclass+%2Bplugin+%2Bname+is%3Aa) is always available.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I customize output of tables of records in wp-admin/edit.php?

You can't. **@brasofilo** explained you why in [his answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/111289/customize-a-wp-posts-list-table-class/113276#113276).

**A workaround:**

1. Remove the standard edit link from admin menu, using `remove_menu_page` / `remove_submenu_page`
2. Add your own menu element, that will include customized file
3. For that customized file, copy the most part from core and just edit what you want.